# how do you redirect to subdirectory after the / in the url to a page

Tags: html, subdomain, subdirectory

I am pretty new to every language and don't have a lot of experience. I am looking for a code or a way to redirect a word to a page,  for example.

www.example.com/admin

will let you go to www.example.com/admin/login.html or php

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the server has a configuration to an index file, which by default is index.html, index.htm or index.php, but the specifics depend on your server.

The obvious solution is to configure the server to use `login.php` or whatever file you have as index file. Most servers also allow you to send a HTTP code which indicate that the target has moved (HTTP redirect). I won't go into specifics here, as you've not specified which HTTP server you use.

However, this all probably misses the point, as in most web applications, you'll want to redirect if no login information is present. For a solution in PHP, you want to look into the `header(…)` function.